# Click Event to parent in Vue with multiple components

Tags: vue.js

Can't find a solution to my problem when using the same child component multiple times..
Maybe someone can help me? I feel like this is very easy.

I have a parent, which loads the same child component multiple times. The child component has an option to edit another component that is loaded by the parent.

It is working, but when I click edit, it shows all the components. I want it to show the component right beneath it.

Here is my code.

**Parent**:

```
<template>


<div>
    <Card title="E-mail address" content="test@test.com" @clicked="onClickChild"></Card>
    <Address v-if="this.editCard" />
    <hr>
    <Card title="Shipping method" content="Post 5 dollar"></Card>
    <Shipment v-if="this.editCard" />
    <hr>
    <Card title="Payment method" content="Bank by wire"></Card>
    <Payment v-if="this.editCard" />
    <hr>
    <Terms></Terms>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Address from './forms/Address';
import Shipment from './forms/Shipment';
import Payment from './forms/Payment';
import Terms from './Terms';
import Card from './Card';

export default {
  name: 'OPC',
  components: {
    Address,
    Shipment,
    Payment,
    Terms,
    Card
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editCard: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClickChild (value) {
      this.editCard = true
    }
  }
};


</script>
```

**Child (Card.vue)**

```
    <template>
  <div class="card mb-1 p-1">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-space-between">

        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>

        <span @click="editCard()"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></span>

    </div>
    <p class="m-0">{{ content }}</p>
  </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Card',
  props: ['title', 'content'],
  methods: {
    editCard () {
      this.$emit('clicked', 'someValue')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: make it an object `v-if="edit.address"`, then set the specific object `@clicked="() => edit.address = true"`, basically if you want multiple, then you need to use an object or array, as single boolean value wont work, but you could do `v-if="editCard === 'address'"` and `@clicked="() => editCard = 'address'"`, but then its only editing a single item at a time

Comment: what don't you get? change `@clicked="onClickChild"` to `@clicked="() => editCard = 'address'"`, then change `<Address v-if="this.editCard" />` to `<Address v-if="editCard === 'address'" />`

Comment: Wow that works, thanks. Still don't understand how, but it's fine. Thanks